# Insert double quotes in only a certain column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file where I need to change the formatting of the 3rd column.

Here is an example line of the .gtf file (tab delimited):

```
chr1    CAT     gene_id=RP11-54O7.16;transcript_id=ENST00000607769.1-1;
chr1    CAT     gene_id=RP11-54O7.16;transcript_id=ENST00000607769.1-2;
```

I need to remove the equal sign and put quotation marks around the gene and transcript names like so:

```
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1";
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2";
```

Is this something I can accomplish with `awk` or `sed`? My main issue is inserting the quotes multiple times within the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed 's/=/ "/g; s/;/";/g' file.gtf
```

or

```
sed -e 's/=/ "/g' -e 's/;/";/g' file.gtf
```

```
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1";
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ split($0, a , " +|[=;]", seps); '\
'print a[1] seps[1] a[2] seps[2] a[3] " \"" a[4] "\";" a[5] " \"" a[6] "\""; }' input

chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1"
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2"
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for the 4th arg to split(). The third arg is a regexp, btw, not a string, so it should be in regexp, not string, delimiters - `/ +|[=;]/`.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk -v replace=' "' -v bo='"' '{gsub(/=/,replace,$0);gsub(";",bo";",$0);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1";
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2";
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
l=open('filename','r')
for i in l:
    print i.strip().replace('=',' "').replace(';','";')
```

output

```
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1";
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/=\([^;]*\)/ "\1"/g' file
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-1";
chr1    CAT     gene_id "RP11-54O7.16";transcript_id "ENST00000607769.1-2";
```